# SQLite disk space used by empty column?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table with with a column that is usually null. I'm wondering about the tradeoffs between having a normal column vs an associated table: For example, let's say I have a table of transactions (`txns`) and only a few of them have an associated `stock_symbol`. Option 1 looks like:

```sql
create table txns (
   id text,
   ... normal columns ...
   stock_symbol text -- often null
)
```

While option 2, with an associated table, looks like:

```sql
create table txns ( id text, ... )
create table txn_stock (
    txn_id text,
    stock_symbol text
)
```

Obviously option 2 makes it a bit more complicated to query. But option 1, I'm assuming, takes more space. How much more space does it take? What is the cost per row in disk space of a column like `stock_symbol text` when it is null, or the empty string?

Comment: If there is any functional dependency between the normal columns in table txns and stock_symbol, then from the point of view of rdbms normalisation, the correct thing to do is having a separate table and relate it to txns by foreign key.

Comment: Reading https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html should give you an idea, but basically a null value takes 1 byte iirc, as does an empty string.